# Images broken on server

Tags: html, image, href, broken-image

I am making a webpage and I am including these images, when I run the page off of notepadd++ everything works fine but after I upload it to the server and I try to run it, the images are broken and I am getting this message on the console : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
<a href="games/rockpaper/main.html"><img class = "rock" src="images/rockpaper.JPG" alt="Thumbnail of the rock-paper-scissors game"><a>


<a href="games/typing/TypingTest.html"><img class = "typing" src="images/typing.JPG" alt="Thumbnaul of the typing test game"><a>
```

Comment: Is your images folder in the same folder as whatever file this code is in?

Comment: The html files are in a folder called "final"
The images are in Final > images > img.jpg

Comment: And the html page is also in this "Final" directory?

Comment: Final > .pages. Final > images > img.jpg.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not entirely sure what you're saying in your comment. I suspect two things:

1. Make sure that your image src is relative to your actual directory layout. For example if the file that contains that code is in "home", make sure that your images are in "home/images/xx.JPG"
2. If you're developing on a windows computer and hosting on a unix server, make sure that the case of the directories and files are identical. Windows is not case sensitive where as unix is. If you uploaded typing.jpg and are looking for typing.JPG, it will not find it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I fixed it . You know what it was? JPG was upper case.

Answer (score 0):

The JPG as the end of the src link needs to be lower case. for example

```
src="images/rockpaper.JPG"
```

should be

```
 src="images/rockpaper.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close them with `</a>`, not `<a>`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MarkParnell I don't know about this one. It seems like a fine answer to me, even if it might not be correct.

Comment: @BlueIce It's more of a comment.